# only read certain columns from a csv

Tags: vb.net, csv, export-to-csv, text-parsing

so I have a csv file that has extra commas in it.  I know I won't ever need anything after a specific column.  So basically any information after column 12 I won't need.  I don't have a say on how the csv looks when it gets to me, so I can't change it there.  I was wondering if there is a way to just read the first 12 columns and ignore the rest of the csv file.

this is what the code looks like now.

thank you for any help

```
Private Sub GetData(ByVal Path As String, ByRef DG As DataGridView, Optional ByVal NoHeader As Boolean = False)
    Dim Fields(100) As String
    Dim Start As Integer = 1
    If NoHeader Then Start = 0
    If Not File.Exists(Path) Then
        Return
    End If
    Dim Lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(Path)
    Lines(0) = Lines(0).Replace(Chr(34), "")
    Fields = Lines(0).Split(",")
    If NoHeader Then
        For I = 1 To Fields.Count - 1
            Fields(I) = Str(I)
        Next
    End If

    dt = New DataTable()

    For Each Header As String In Fields
        dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(Header.Trim()))
        Dim desiredSize As Integer = 11

        While dt.Columns.Count > desiredSize
            dt.Columns.RemoveAt(desiredSize)
        End While

    Next
    For I = Start To Lines.Count - 1
        Lines(I) = Lines(I).Replace(Chr(34), "")
        Fields = Lines(I).Split(",")

        Dim dr As DataRow = dt.Rows.Add()
        For j = 0 To Fields.Count - 1
            dr(j) = Fields(j).Trim()
        Next

    Next

    DG.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

Comment: With the standard ReadLines methods you cannot stop reading at a certain point of the line. You could try to search some external libraries specific for parsing files if they have this option (One that comes to mind is [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) but it is probably overkill just for this. So, apart from the convuluted create/delete pattern when you create the columns you have already a 'need to debug' working approach here

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel, you might wish to take a look at the [TextFieldParser Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Really all you need to do is, in the for loop where you iterate through `Fields` at the bottom, replace `For j = 0 to Fields.Count - 1` with `For j = 0 to 11`.